# How to query a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLENAME + "(" +
            COLUMNS[0] + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMNS[1] + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMNS[2] + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMNS[3] + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMNS[4] + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMNS[5] + " TEXT NOT NULL  " +
            ");";
```

And query all data from database:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst(); // need to start the cursor first...!
        while(!cur.isAfterLast()) { // while not end of data stored in table...
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setId(cur.getInt(0));
            emp.setName(cur.getString(1));
            emp.setCharge(cur.getString(2));
            emp.setDepartament(cur.getString(3));
            emp.setPhone(cur.getString(4));
            emp.setEmail(cur.getString(5));
            employees.add(emp);
            cur.moveToNext(); // next loop
        }
        cur.close(); // !important
        return employees;
    }
```

I want to query all data if `employee name =="ali"`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to query all data if employee name =="ali".

**3rd** and **4th** parameter is available in `query` method for adding `WHERE clause` in query.

Do it as:

```
Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, 
                      "name=?", 
                      new String[] { "ali" }, 
                      null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

with

```
 Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, columns[1]+" = ?", new String[]{"ali"}, null, null, null);
```

The 3rd parameter in `db.query()` method is "selection statement"
and the 4th parameter is "selection arguments".

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will also help you prevent from `sql injection`

```
   Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, columns[1]+" = ?", new String[]{"ali"}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this cursor to query all data if employee name `=="ali"`:-

```
String selection = COLUMNS[x] + " = " + "'" + ali + "'";
Cursor cur = db.query(dbHelper.TABLENAME, columns, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

Here `COLUMNS[x]` should be the column containing the employee names and "x" be the respective column number.

This cursor will fetch you only the records/tuples for the employee named "ali".